# Averaging and plotting a non-systematic/arranged data using Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a non-systematic/arranged data as follows:

```
+-------------+------------------+
    |      x      |        y         |
    +-------------+------------------+
    | 0.049098    | 82854.2105263158 |
    | 0.049058    | 82472.2368421053 |
    | 0.066427    | 84358.3421052632 |
    | 0.066465    | 83842.9210526316 |
    | 0.06095     | 71843.6052631579 |
    | 0.060989    | 71951.7368421053 |
    | 0.066999    | 84068.5526315789 |
    | 0.067037    | 83808.5263157895 |
    | 0.089523    | 101753.684210526 |
    | 0.089483    | 101556.842105263 |
    | 0.084839    | 97206.7105263158 |
    | 0.084876    | 97108.8421052632 |
    | 0.063842    | 88679.5263157895 |
    | 0.063802    | 88309.9210526316 |
    | 0.037228    | 11944.3947368421 |
    | 0.037268    | 11993.3421052632 |
    | 0.029821    |  8830.4131578947 |
    | 0.029861    |  8822.0815789474 |
    | 0.03014     |  8938.6973684211 |
    | 0.03018     |  8964.6868421053 |
    | 0.00817     |           138170 |
    | 0.0081363   |           137640 |
    | 0.093207    | 103233.947368421 |
    | 0.093244    | 103177.631578947 |
    | 0.097776    | 106011.578947368 |
    | 0.097814    | 106073.421052632 |
    | 0.0089158   |           135440 |
    | 0.0088818   |           136660 |
    | 0.02952     | 90309.3421052632 |
    | 0.029481    |            89523 |
    | 0.034049    | 10589.8342105263 |
    | 0.034089    | 10666.1973684211 |
    | 0.086063    | 98010.6315789474 |
    | 0.0861      | 98108.9736842105 |
    | 0.045509    | 82204.8947368421 |
    | 0.045469    | 81673.8947368421 |
    | 0.03045     | 87057.7105263158 |
    | 0.030411    | 89830.2105263158 |
    | 0.0072205   |  5150.6763157895 |
    | 0.0072587   |  5151.1710526316 |
    | 0.068255    | 83407.7894736842 |
    | 0.068293    | 83492.1052631579 |
    | 0.06145     | 73967.8684210526 |
    | 0.061488    | 74132.5789473684 |
    | 0.027424    |  8204.1210526316 |
    | 0.027464    |  8205.0763157895 |
    | 0.027184    |  8141.3947368421 |
    | 0.027224    |   8146.002631579 |
    | 0.046346    | 81611.4736842105 |
    | 0.046306    | 81550.8947368421 |
    | 0.058526    | 58270.5526315789 |
    | 0.058564    | 58725.2631578947 |
    | 0.051402    | 29829.4473684211 |
    | 0.05144     | 29684.2105263158 |
    | 0.0014855   |  5757.1894736842 |
    | 0.0015227   |  5742.7289473684 |
    | 0.068954    |            91718 |
    | 0.068914    | 91719.2894736842 |
    | 0.091635    | 104896.052631579 |
    | 0.091595    | 104854.210526316 |
    | 0.038524    | 82972.3421052632 |
    | 0.038484    | 83128.8684210526 |
    | 0.0094275   |           133930 |
    | 0.0093933   |           133770 |
    | 0.098839    | 105576.842105263 |
    | 0.098833    | 105552.105263158 |
    | 0.0087119   |           136020 |
    | 0.0086779   |           136080 |
    | 0.049537    | 82553.5789473684 |
    | 0.049497    | 82109.6578947368 |
    | 0.0099132   |  5289.7473684211 |
    | 0.0099519   |  5290.3421052632 |
    | 0.069273    | 91867.1842105263 |
    | 0.069233    |            91812 |
    | 0.039564    | 12888.1578947368 |
    | 0.039603    | 13071.3947368421 |
    | 0.023351    |  7234.2473684211 |
    | 0.023391    |  7244.1789473684 |
    | 0.085419    | 94590.4210526316 |
    | 0.085379    | 94557.6578947368 |
    | 0.077463    | 90603.6315789474 |
    | 0.0775      | 90673.7105263158 |
    | 0.015378    |  5389.0578947369 |
    | 0.015417    |  5376.9263157895 |
    | 0.090262    | 101246.315789474 |
    | 0.090299    | 101226.578947368 |
    | 0.090969    | 101686.052631579 |
    | 0.091006    | 101689.210526316 |
    | 0.040275    | 13386.1578947368 |
    | 0.040314    | 13415.2368421053 |
    | 0.065053    | 84553.3157894737 |
    | 0.065091    | 84354.8157894737 |
    | 0.041064    | 13609.8684210526 |
    | 0.041103    |            13574 |
    | 0.028143    |   8369.052631579 |
    | 0.028183    |  8367.3710526316 |
    | 0.041057    | 81182.5789473684 |
    | 0.041018    | 82941.2368421053 |
    | 0.049623    | 23859.1315789474 |
    | 0.049662    | 24037.2368421053 |
    | 0.036984    | 83875.2368421053 |
    | 0.036945    | 84167.6315789474 |
    | 0.083188    | 94965.8947368421 |
    | 0.083148    | 94978.3421052632 |
    | 0.058336    |            57671 |
    | 0.058374    | 57815.0263157895 |
    | 0.089369    | 100686.315789474 |
    | 0.089406    | 100711.052631579 |
    | 0.069592    | 92141.2368421053 |
    | 0.069552    | 92152.5789473684 |
    | 0.025793    | 94431.7894736842 |
    | 0.025755    | 94648.2368421053 |
    | 0.098749    | 105945.526315789 |
    | 0.098743    | 105963.421052632 |
    | 0.0098043   |           132600 |
    | 0.00977     |           133260 |
    | 0.060082    | 62819.4210526316 |
    | 0.06012     | 62454.0789473684 |
    | 0.033059    |            86467 |
    | 0.03302     | 86483.9736842105 |
    | 0.0036852   |           153970 |
    | 0.003653    |           154510 |
    | 0.0085422   |           136250 |
    | 0.0085083   |           136650 |
    | 0.056689    | 84997.6578947368 |
    | 0.056649    |            85002 |
    | 0.096125    | 105024.736842105 |
    | 0.096162    | 105118.421052632 |
    | 0.021898    |           101320 |
    | 0.02186     |           101500 |
    | 0.076134    | 94468.3157894737 |
    | 0.076094    | 94467.5789473684 |
    | 0.053904    | 42192.3157894737 |
    | 0.053942    |  42010.052631579 |
    | 0.098707    |           106005 |
    | 0.098701    | 106008.947368421 |
    | 0.049546    | 23698.6052631579 |
    | 0.049584    | 23714.5263157895 |
    | 0.067636    |            90985 |
    | 0.067596    |            90934 |
    | 0.053851    | 84300.7368421053 |
    | 0.053811    | 83469.3157894737 |
    | 0.075979    |          88750.5 |
    | 0.076016    | 88815.7894736842 |
    | 0.071428    | 93062.2894736842 |
    | 0.071388    | 93069.7368421053 |
    | 0.0036544   |  5232.8736842105 |
    | 0.0036921   |   5239.252631579 |
    | 0.047332    | 17610.8947368421 |
    | 0.047371    | 17750.7894736842 |
    | 0.03975     | 82067.8684210526 |
    | 0.03971     | 83408.6578947368 |
    | 0.0038426   |          5238.65 |
    | 0.0038802   |  5240.4131578947 |
    | 0.014999    |           116980 |
    | 0.014964    |           116700 |
    | 0.06467     | 84685.7368421053 |
    | 0.064709    | 84580.6578947368 |
    | 0.047137    | 17372.6578947368 |
    | 0.047176    | 17571.9473684211 |
    | 0.083467    | 96096.2368421053 |
    | 0.083504    | 96070.5263157895 |
    | 0.037576    | 82819.5789473684 |
    | 0.037536    | 84310.5526315789 |
    | 0.016188    | 114852.368421053 |
    | 0.016152    | 116141.842105263 |
    | 0.016477    | 113262.631578947 |
    | 0.016441    |           113310 |
    | 0.02246     |           100100 |
    | 0.022423    |           100270 |
    | 0.005354    |  5153.0815789474 |
    | 0.005392    |  5142.1552631579 |
    | 0.0284      |            90929 |
    | 0.028362    | 91147.2631578947 |
    | 0.083626    | 94884.6578947368 |
    | 0.083586    | 94890.3421052632 |
    | 0.06532     | 89854.8947368421 |
    | 0.06528     |            89501 |
    | 0.094505    | 106278.947368421 |
    | 0.094465    | 106231.578947368 |
    | 0.076387    | 88890.1315789474 |
    | 0.076424    | 89590.1578947368 |
    | 0.055207    | 47767.2894736842 |
    | 0.055245    | 47816.7631578947 |
    | 0.013148    |           121650 |
    | 0.013113    |           122170 |
    | 0.058754    | 59487.1842105263 |
    | 0.058792    | 59770.1578947368 |
    | 0.089592    | 100777.631578947 |
    | 0.089629    | 100783.421052632 |
    | 0.038813    | 12513.2368421053 |
    | 0.038852    | 12835.4473684211 |
    | 0.040621    | 82482.0789473684 |
    | 0.040581    | 82730.3947368421 |
    | 0.079242    | 92299.3157894737 |
    | 0.079279    | 92281.5789473684 |
    | 0.088328    | 98621.8947368421 |
    | 0.088288    | 98518.9736842105 |
    | 0.044673    | 81556.3157894737 |
    | 0.044633    | 81528.5789473684 |
    | 0.0033321   | 155138.947368421 |
    | 0.0033001   |           155460 |
    | 0.056449    |            84852 |
    | 0.056409    |          84876.5 |
    | 0.056289    |            84755 |
    | 0.056249    | 84690.4473684211 |
    | 0.083825    | 94857.6052631579 |
    | 0.083786    | 94850.7105263158 |
    | 0.097551    | 105735.526315789 |
    | 0.097589    | 105823.947368421 |
    | 0.086991    | 98877.4473684211 |
    | 0.087028    | 98838.8421052632 |
    | 0.017095    | 111495.263157895 |
    | 0.017058    | 111965.263157895 |
    | 0.071779    | 82918.1315789474 |
    | 0.071817    | 82398.5789473684 |
    | 0.054287    | 43715.9736842105 |
    | 0.054326    | 43708.8421052632 |
    | 0.082112    | 95046.4210526316 |
    | 0.082072    |            95044 |
    | 0.068369    | 83746.3157894737 |
    | 0.068407    | 83829.8684210526 |
    | 0.027104    |  8103.8631578947 |
    | 0.027144    |          8118.85 |
    | 0.011047    |           129060 |
    | 0.011012    |           128640 |
    | 0.084582    | 94701.0263157895 |
    | 0.084543    | 94672.7368421053 |
    | 0.050495    | 83239.7631578947 |
    | 0.050455    | 83211.9210526316 |
    | 0.087251    | 99002.3421052632 |
    | 0.087288    | 99021.7368421053 |
    | 0.060446    |            86629 |
    | 0.060406    |            86340 |
    | 0.036315    | 83643.4210526316 |
    | 0.036275    | 83463.7368421053 |
    | 0.030699    |  9294.2289473684 |
    | 0.030739    |  9340.0578947369 |
    | 0.039682    | 13377.1842105263 |
    | 0.039722    | 13303.4736842105 |
    | 0.071364    | 83794.9210526316 |
    | 0.071401    |          83361.5 |
    | 0.080319    |          94917.5 |
    | 0.080279    | 94918.3157894737 |
    | 0.072505    | 93484.7894736842 |
    | 0.072465    | 93468.6315789474 |
    | 0.034743    | 84187.2894736842 |
    | 0.034704    |  84421.552631579 |
    | 0.066159    | 89952.6842105263 |
    | 0.066119    |            89935 |
    | 0.007565    |  5184.3157894737 |
    | 0.0076033   |  5181.4763157895 |
    | 0.020563    |  6035.7105263158 |
    | 0.020603    |  6043.1578947369 |
    | 0.046007    | 15889.9736842105 |
    | 0.046046    | 15788.5526315789 |
    | 0.017351    |  5446.0736842105 |
    | 0.01739     |  5445.7078947369 |
    | 0.05481     | 84160.3684210526 |
    | 0.05477     | 84138.1578947368 |
    | 0.063714    | 84575.8947368421 |
    | 0.063752    | 84555.3684210526 |
    | 0.038338    | 12504.8421052632 |
    | 0.038377    | 12557.4736842105 |
    | 0.011037    |  5331.7342105263 |
    | 0.011076    |  5325.8736842105 |
    | 0.002124    |           158640 |
    | 0.0020924   |           158730 |
    | 0.014356    |  5376.3447368421 |
    | 0.014396    |  5381.3842105263 |
    | 0.066359    |            90386 |
    | 0.066319    | 90076.0789473684 |
    | 0.017715    |           109750 |
    | 0.017678    |           109140 |
    | 0.013846    |          5385.45 |
    | 0.013886    |  5373.5157894737 |
    | 0.032356    | 87047.1842105263 |
    | 0.032317    | 87202.2368421053 |
    | 0.00022592  |  6227.5342105263 |
    | 0.00026284  |  6525.5394736842 |
    | 0.026944    |  8170.5052631579 |
    | 0.026984    |  8161.0552631579 |
    | 0.067684    |          84077.5 |
    | 0.067722    | 84406.1578947368 |
    | 0.00056151  | 154602.631578947 |
    | 0.00053058  | 154025.263157895 |
    | 0.01369     |  5392.0289473684 |
    | 0.013729    |  5388.5763157895 |
    | 0.069712    | 92249.6315789474 |
    | 0.069672    |            92203 |
    | 0.090336    | 101292.631578947 |
    | 0.041221    |          13574.5 |
    | 0.041261    | 13649.3157894737 |
    | 0.088248    | 98377.2631578947 |
    | 0.032747    | 86214.6578947368 |
    | 0.032707    | 86199.7105263158 |
    | 0.018063    |  5426.3657894737 |
    | 0.018102    |  5400.5368421053 |
    | 0.037221    |            82838 |
    | 0.037182    | 82739.0526315789 |
    | 0.079316    | 92217.8421052632 |
    | -0.00010567 | 22281.2894736842 |
    | -0.00010105 | 16333.2105263158 |
    | 0.073491    | 86313.1315789474 |
    | 0.073528    | 85860.3157894737 |
    | 0.069113    | 91703.1052631579 |
    | 0.069073    | 91686.2894736842 |
    | 0.077489    | 94662.4210526316 |
    | 0.077449    | 94656.2631578947 |
    | 0.064242    | 89154.7368421053 |
    | 0.064202    | 88866.8947368421 |
    | 0.032512    |            86583 |
    | 0.032473    |            86524 |
    | 0.062564    |            88165 |
    | 0.062524    | 87488.0789473684 |
    | 0.036792    | 11964.3947368421 |
    | 0.036831    | 11973.1315789474 |
    | 0.027823    |  8258.2552631579 |
    | 0.027863    |  8251.5105263158 |
    | 0.078008    | 94725.7105263158 |
    | 0.077968    | 94721.5263157895 |
    | 0.071747    | 93315.2105263158 |
    | 0.071707    | 93235.3421052632 |
    | 0.04546     | 15240.2631578947 |
    | 0.045499    | 15235.0526315789 |
    | 0.044482    |            14225 |
    | 0.044521    | 14200.3947368421 |
    | 0.024748    |  7701.9210526316 |
    | 0.024788    |  7717.5815789474 |
    | 0.046545    | 82522.7105263158 |
    | 0.046505    | 83732.5789473684 |
    | 0.033646    | 85096.8947368421 |
    | 0.033607    |            85049 |
    | 0.042923    | 82511.9473684211 |
    | 0.042883    | 82387.2894736842 |
    | 0.03076     | 88367.9210526316 |
    | 0.030722    | 88564.7105263158 |
    | 0.087696    | 99199.4473684211 |
    | 0.087733    | 99362.7368421053 |
    | 0.026106    |  8012.5921052632 |
    | 0.026145    |  8007.1894736842 |
    | 0.098174    | 106645.263157895 |
    | 0.098134    | 106593.421052632 |
    | 0.086654    | 95285.7368421053 |
    | 0.086614    | 95258.9210526316 |
    | 0.047382    | 82383.3421052632 |
    | 0.047342    | 81833.7105263158 |
    | 0.085247    | 97339.8157894737 |
    | 0.085284    | 97644.3157894737 |
    | 0.04409     | 14122.2368421053 |
    | 0.044129    | 14113.7368421053 |
    | 0.047901    |            81497 |
    | 0.047861    | 81418.3157894737 |
    | 0.026825    | 92594.1315789474 |
    | 0.026787    | 92662.3684210526 |
    | 0.088625    | 100252.184210526 |
    | 0.088662    | 100399.131578947 |
    | 0.029461    |   8646.752631579 |
    | 0.029501    |  8660.6105263158 |
    | 0.01543     |           115970 |
    | 0.015394    |           115980 |
    | 0.021836    |  6580.3368421053 |
    | 0.021876    |  6564.8184210526 |
    | 0.057528    |            85296 |
    | 0.057488    |            85006 |
    | 0.032903    |            86497 |
    | 0.032864    |            86557 |
    | 0.042874    | 13655.0263157895 |
    | 0.042913    | 13685.4473684211 |
    | 0.026175    |          94264.5 |
    | 0.026136    |            94268 |
    | 0.023931    |  97683.052631579 |
    | 0.023893    | 97162.5789473684 |
    | 0.086434    | 98644.9736842105 |
    | 0.086471    | 98392.6052631579 |
    | 0.0097586   |  5293.0263157895 |
    | 0.0097972   |  5290.9763157895 |
    | 0.0019695   |   5567.652631579 |
    | 0.0020067   |  5540.9947368421 |
    | 0.062218    | 78864.3947368421 |
    | 0.062257    | 79100.7105263158 |
    | 0.085658    | 94532.6052631579 |
    | 0.085618    | 94520.1842105263 |
    | 0.07039     | 92623.2631578947 |
    | 0.070351    | 92675.2894736842 |
    | 0.096459    |           106720 |
    | 0.096419    | 106790.789473684 |
    | 0.059167    |            85700 |
    | 0.059127    |            85778 |
    | 0.034272    | 84811.6842105263 |
    | 0.034233    | 84255.4736842105 |
    | 0.024987    |  7870.9342105263 |
    | 0.025027    |  7889.0263157895 |
    | 0.037743    |            11876 |
    | 0.037783    | 12060.9473684211 |
    | 0.042991    | 13413.9210526316 |
    | 0.043031    | 13357.1315789474 |
    | 0.097974    | 107210.263157895 |
    | 0.097935    | 107250.263157895 |
    | 0.095788    | 104838.947368421 |
    | 0.095825    | 104789.473684211 |
    | 0.098491    | 105937.894736842 |
    | 0.098529    | 105891.842105263 |
    | 0.062124    |            87670 |
    | 0.062084    |            87664 |
    | 0.046864    | 82101.0263157895 |
    | 0.046824    | 82290.8157894737 |
    | 0.016087    |  5395.5868421053 |
    | 0.016127    |  5394.0657894737 |
    | 0.065015    | 84096.0526315789 |
    | 0.090918    | 104228.684210526 |
    | 0.090878    | 104018.421052632 |
    | 0.065664    | 84754.8947368421 |
    | 0.065702    | 84734.4473684211 |
    | 0.012619    |           123970 |
    | 0.012584    | 124412.631578947 |
    | 0.064561    | 89115.0263157895 |
    | 0.064521    | 88996.7368421053 |
    | 0.048382    | 20419.7368421053 |
    | 0.048421    | 20430.5526315789 |
    | 0.07741     | 94648.2631578947 |
    | 0.010148    |           131200 |
    | 0.010114    |           131180 |
    | 0.031421    | 88356.7105263158 |
    | 0.031382    | 88397.8157894737 |
    | 0.0018949   |  5593.8789473684 |
    | 0.0019322   |  5588.7631578947 |
    | 0.056048    | 50006.8157894737 |
    | 0.056086    | 50654.4736842105 |
    | 0.024468    |  7700.4473684211 |
    | 0.024508    |  7719.8421052632 |
    | 0.078566    | 94788.3947368421 |
    | 0.078526    | 94786.3421052632 |
    | 0.089045    |           100410 |
    | 0.089005    | 100279.210526316 |
    | 0.026225    |           7953.7 |
    | 0.026265    |  7956.9105263158 |
    | 0.021636    |           100290 |
    | 0.021598    |           100420 |
    | 0.013715    |           120830 |
    | 0.01368     |           121700 |
    | 0.05765     | 55683.2631578947 |
    | 0.057689    | 55756.9210526316 |
    | 0.0025295   |  5411.2236842105 |
    | 0.0025668   |  5389.6973684211 |
    | 0.046704    |            82967 |
    | 0.046665    |  82828.552631579 |
    | 0.050615    |            81974 |
    | 0.050575    |            82113 |
    | 0.071907    | 93276.4210526316 |
    | 0.071867    | 93275.5526315789 |
    | 0.077569    | 94671.2631578947 |
    | 0.077529    | 94667.1578947368 |
    | 0.057079    |            53966 |
    | 0.057117    | 54124.1842105263 |
    | 0.010649    |  5281.5394736842 |
    | 0.010688    |  5270.6394736842 |
    | 0.051093    | 29069.0263157895 |
    | 0.051132    | 29441.1315789474 |
    | 0.019257    |           105790 |
    | 0.01922     |           105980 |
    | 0.059931    | 62444.0789473684 |
    | 0.059968    | 62989.5263157895 |
    | 0.087491    | 96730.8684210526 |
    | 0.087451    | 96664.7894736842 |
    | 0.091379    | 101955.263157895 |
    | 0.091416    | 101995.526315789 |
    | 0.095143    | 106449.210526316 |
    | 0.095103    | 106461.578947368 |
    | 0.087889    | 97553.9210526316 |
    | 0.08785     |            97504 |
    | 0.024428    |  7661.7315789474 |
    | 0.014788    |  5407.6947368421 |
    | 0.014828    |  5407.6315789474 |
    | 0.083541    | 96009.3947368421 |
    | 0.037664    | 12100.8157894737 |
    | 0.037704    | 11912.6842105263 |
    | 0.070311    | 92669.6842105263 |
    | 0.031458    |   9692.202631579 |
    | 0.031498    |  9714.7368421053 |
    | 0.072561    | 84201.3421052632 |
    | 0.072598    | 84699.2105263158 |
    | 0.067876    | 91029.6578947368 |
    | 0.067836    | 91104.0263157895 |
    | 0.035998    | 11560.7105263158 |
    | 0.036037    | 11357.4473684211 |
    | 0.042963    |            82322 |
    | 0.022912    |           100400 |
    | 0.022874    | 99962.6842105263 |
    | 0.0064626   |           143520 |
    | 0.0064294   |           143710 |
    | 0.085499    | 94484.4210526316 |
    | 0.085459    |          94543.5 |
    | 0.091528    | 102023.684210526 |
    +-------------+------------------+
```

When I tried to plot it using the line plot, I am getting a really messy plot,
[image]
But if I plot it using the symbols then it is making more sense, which is as follows:
[image]

As you can clearly notice that there are 2 separate curves (upper and lower) in the plot. I wanted to take the average of the 5-10 adjacent points of upper and lower curve to make the plot smoother (shown by the arrows in the previous figure) and then finally plot it using the line plot. The major issue in taking the average is that the Python/Pandas takes the average of the adjacent data point which is specifically the upper or lower portion of graph (since randomly arranged data). I tried to write a small code to plot it but could not achieve the desired output.

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import math
    
    
    dataframe1 = pd.read_csv('excel_file_trial.csv')
    
    plt.figure(1) # 
    plt.scatter(dataframe1.iloc[:,0], dataframe1.iloc[0:,1], s=1, marker="o",  facecolors='none', edgecolor='black', linewidths=2)
    plt.xlabel("x", fontsize=17)
    plt.ylabel("y", fontsize=17)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("trialv0.png", bbox_inches = "tight", format='png', dpi=300)
       
    # figure 3
    plt.figure(3) # 
    plt.plot(dataframe1.iloc[:,0], dataframe1.iloc[0:,1], color="green", linewidth=3.5)
    plt.xlabel("x", fontsize=17)
    plt.ylabel("y", fontsize=17)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("trialv2.png", bbox_inches = "tight", format='png', dpi=300)
```

Could anyone please help/suggest in this regard. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: the right end (0.08-0.1) seems especially problematic (impossible?) to separate. there's really no other data besides `x` and `y` that could help discriminate the traces?

Comment: @tdy thanks for looking it closely, but unfortunately the data file is very large and thus not able to upload it completely. Is there some other to upload the data file ?