# How to use mulpile conditioning in pandas series, select few and take moving average

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

With reference to the previous post:
[Averaging and plotting a non-systematic/arranged data using Python/Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68192773/averaging-and-plotting-a-non-systematic-arranged-data-using-python-pandas)

I found a very crude and native way to do this:

1. Post process the data frame to produce new variable/series (pandas.core.series.Series)
2. Compare this series to my requirement, store the new variable
3. Take moving average of the new variable and store it for plotting them

The code that I tried looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
theta = math.pi/180
dataframe1 = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv')
x1 = ((1.0/math.cos(-9*theta))*dataframe1.iloc[:,0]/0.1) # created new series as per requirement 
y1 = dataframe1.iloc[0:,1] # created new series as per requirement 

if (x1 > 0.1)&(x1 < 0.75)&(y1 > -0.5)&(y1 < 0.5): # comparing the elements as per requirement 
    x1u = x1.rolling(5).mean # taking moving average for 5 points in x direction
    y1u = y1.rolling(5).mean # taking moving average for 5 points in y direction
```

Unfortunately it is not working and giving me this error, which says:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I know it's a very crude bug, since I am a beginner in Python, thus kindly excuse me for this query. Any comment/suggestion will be kind help, thanks in advance.

Using the @tdy help, I am able to get the error free code, but unfortunately the smooth function makes the plot too flat, this is not what I required, the screenshot is attached herewith.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you should use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) instead of an `if` statement:

```py
# remove the if-statement
conditions = (x1 > 0.1) & (x1 < 0.75) & (y1 > -0.5) & (y1 < 0.5)
x1u = x1.loc[conditions].rolling(5).mean()
y1u = y1.loc[conditions].rolling(5).mean()
```

If you take a look at the output of `(x1 > 0.1) & (x1 < 0.75)` for example, note that the result is a boolean Series. Using `if` on a Series is ambiguous because python doesn't know when to return `True`. Do `all()` elements have to match or just `any()`?

What you're actually trying to do is retrieve the elements at the `True` locations, which is what [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) does.

Comment: Thanks a lot @tdy for your help, your suggestion helped me a lot, now I am getting no errors. But unfortunately I guess the smooth function is making the data looks flat. To show in a better way, I edited my question now.

Comment: @user13680518 these are separate problems. this question is about taking a (multi)conditional moving average, and this answer solves that question. i just took a look at your other question and i'm not sure how to solve that one, but it's more complicated than a conditional rolling mean.